# Wiping dummy database without affecting structure

Tags: c#, mysql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, webmatrix

I've been working on an MVC web application, which I already deployed to a webserver (Arvixe) using Webmatrix 3.

I've Inserted alot of dummy records for testing in the database, and now the website is online with all the dummy data.

My question is (and I've searched for it) : Now that my application is ready for production, how can I Wipe all data from the database (start fresh) without affecting any structure?

I've tried some solutions but ended up with more errors than I can count ( I am still new to MVC)

What I need to do is, Publish my website with 0 records (in my case, estates) and start uploading real data into the database, instead of the dummy ones.

Info :

1- I am using MVC4 Visual Studio 2012
2- I am using Entity Framework
3- I am using Webmatrix linked to my web hosting (Arvixe)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "without affecting any structure?" ?

Comment: I should've said schema, I want to wipe all data without affecting the schema of the database

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with your set-up, but what really stopping you running a mysql sql statement to truncate data in your table(s) and re-insert/update with real data?